# Firebase list length or count Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

here is my problem. I need to get a count of how many items are in a firebase list.

***Firebase info:***

```
foods
     randompushid
          title: apple,
          comboQuery: apple23523526(userid)
```

***Angular Code:***

```
this.foods= this.firebaseDB.list('/foods', {

                            query: {
                                orderByChild: 'comboQuery',
                                equalTo: data.Name + userId
                            }

                        });
```

The list above works great. I can put it into an *ngfor and it works as intended. This is all inside a save button prompt, and I just want to prevent adding another food with the same combo query.

***What I've attempted to do***

```
this.supplements.subscribe(items => {

                          var ayy = items.length;
                          alert(ayy);
}
```

The alert tends to display the right length at some point but it seems to repeat and I can't use the variable outside of the subscribe function. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is my last bug before release and I've searched everywhere for a fix.

***edit***

```
this.supplements.subscribe(items => {
                            ayy = items.length;
                            if (ayy == 0) {
                                this.foods.push({
                                    title: data.Name,
                                    uid: userId,
                                    comboQuery: data.Name + userId
                                });

                            }

                            else {
                                alert("exists");
                            }

                        })
```

I have ayy = 0 at the top of the addfood() function
And it keeps saying exists regardless

Comment: It looks like you're scoping the variable solely inside the subscribe - If you define var ayy in the component, and then reference it inside the subscribe by this.ayy = items.length, does that not work?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I'm going to copy my comment to an answer so you can close the question out properly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're scoping the variable solely inside the subscribe - If you define `var ayy` in the component, then you can reference it inside the subscribe by `this.ayy = items.length`

Comment: Declare the variable at the top. var ayy;  Then inside the function don't use var again, use this.ayy = items.length, and if (this.ayy) etc. instead.